# Add column to SQL result with unique rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an query where I get a comma seperated string as result, such as;

n,n,n,n

where n can be 0 or 1, and will always be the length of four digits.

I use CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT to get the result as rows. I would like to add a column to this result, and on each row have an unique string, which would be one word.

Like:

```
Value|String
1    | description1
0    | description2
1    | description3
1    | description4
```

I have googled a lot, but can't seem to find how to do this. I hope it is as easy as something like:

```
SELECT myResultAsRows.Value, {'a','b','c','d'} AS String
FROM table
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT ...
WHERE ...
```

I know this seems strange, but on another forum (specific for the tool) they suggested hard-coding it...
I also know it might depend on the server used, but in general, is something like this doable?

As of right now, the query is this:

```
SELECT tagValueRow.Value
FROM t_objectproperties tag
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tag.Value,',') tagValueRow
WHERE tag.Object_ID = #OBJECTID# AND tag.Property = 'myTagName'
```

which results in

```
Value
1
0
1
1
```

for the specified #OBJECTID#.

Thank you!

edit: made the question more detailed, with example closer to reality.

Comment: Your explanation mentions SQL-Server-only functionality, so I added that as the database tag.

Comment: What is your input and expected output ?

Comment: I updated the question now! @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `SUBSTRING` it can be acomplished easily.

Somethink like:

```
SELECT TOP 26 SUBSTRING('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sort_field), 1), *
FROM table
```

It has it limitation: the lenght of 'abc..' string, but with `TOP` will avoid errors.

### Update

It can be done in the same way using the same approach of `ROW_NUMBER` and a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT TOP 5 T.Value, D.Label
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Field) AS Position, tagValueRow.Value AS Value
    FROM t_objectproperties tag
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tag.Value,',') tagValueRow
    WHERE tag.Object_ID = #OBJECTID# AND tag.Property = 'myTagName') T
LEFT JOIN (
    VALUES 
    (1, 'description1'), 
    (2, 'description2'), 
    (3, 'description3'), 
    (4, 'description4'), 
    (5, 'description5')) D(Position, Label) ON T.Position=D.Position
```

Comment: Thank you, will try later. But a,b,c where just examples and will be replaced with words. My bad I guess. I'll try out the concept though

Comment: Oh could you provide more information please?... that words are on a table? if it is... just user `row_number` with a `JOIN`... let me know if I can help.

Comment: I updated the question now, with a bit more detail. The words are not in a table.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! And I understand (:

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Testdata
> (
>     ID INT,
>     String VARCHAR(MAX)
> )
> CREATE TABLE TestList
> (
>     ID INT,
>     String VARCHAR(MAX)
> )
>
> INSERT Testdata SELECT 1,'1,0,1,1'
>
> INSERT TestList SELECT 1,'a,b,c,d'
> ```

> 

> ```
> ;WITH tmp(ID,DataItem, String) AS
> (
>     SELECT
>         ID,
>         LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1),
>         STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
>     FROM Testdata
>     UNION ALL
>
>     SELECT
>         ID,
>         LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1),
>         STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
>     FROM tmp
>     WHERE
>         String > ''
> ),
>  tmp2(ID,DataItem, String) AS  (
>
>
>     SELECT
>         ID,
>         LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1),
>         STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
>     FROM TestList
>     UNION ALL
>
>     SELECT
>         ID,
>         LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1),
>         STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
>     FROM tmp2
>     WHERE
>         String > ''
> )
>
>
>
>
>
> SELECT 
>     p.DataItem,q.DataItem
> FROM tmp AS p
> CROSS APPLY
> (SELECT * FROM tmp2) AS q
> --ORDER BY SomeID
> ```

> ```
> DataItem | DataItem
> :------- | :-------
> 1        | a       
> 0        | a       
> 1        | a       
> 1        | a       
> 1        | b       
> 0        | b       
> 1        | b       
> 1        | b       
> 1        | c       
> 0        | c       
> 1        | c       
> 1        | c       
> 1        | d       
> 0        | d       
> 1        | d       
> 1        | d
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=94673f5efdbcb3d0a79ae95f9916080d)*

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is for each split row to have a value against it in no particular order, then we can cross-join a `VALUES` table to it based on row-number:

```sql
SELECT tagValueRow.Value, desc.description
FROM t_objectproperties tag
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(tag.Value,',') tagValueRow
) tagValueRow
INNER JOIN (VALUES       -- or LEFT JOIN
    ('desciption1', 1),
    ('desciption2', 2),
    ('desciption3', 3),
    ('desciption4', 4),
) desc (description, rn) ON desc.rn = tagValueRow.rn

WHERE tag.Object_ID = #OBJECTID# AND tag.Property = 'myTagName'
```

If you may have more than 4 split avlues, but only want a description against the first 4, change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT`